# Loading an R object gets modified when assigning it to another object

Tags: r, load, character, paste

I have a plot (from `highcharter` package) that I need to load dinamically in a Markdown file.

To do so, I need to assign it to an object that I can call afterwards. But when I do so, It gets converted into a string. Here is what I mean:

This loads my highcharter map correctly, which I can corroborate:

```
x <- 1
load(paste("map_", x, sep = "")

class(map_1)
[1] "highchart"  "htmlwidget"
```

But when I load by assignment to an object, it gets converted to a string. Here is what i mean:

```
mymap <- load(paste("map_", x, sep = ""))
print(mymap)
[1] "map_1" 

class(mymap)
[1] "character"
```

So, how do I load an R object assigning it to another object without converting it to a character?

Comment: That's not how `load` works, see `?load`. `load` will always only ever return the name of the object as a character. If you're using `load` you'll have to do it in two steps, first load and then explicitly do the other assignment. You might be forced to use `assign` if you're using dynamic names.

Comment: (This is one of the reasons I typically always use `saveRDS`/`readRDS` rather than `save`/`load`.)

Comment: An alternative with `load` to using `assign` is to load into an empty environment (`e <- new.env(parent=emptyenv()); load(..., envir=e)`) and either work with it in there or use `e[[ names(e)[1] ]]` to save elsewhere. Concur with `saveRDS` versus `save`.

Comment: You *can* mimic `readRDS` here with: `fake_readRDS <- function(fn) { e <- new.env(parent=emptyenv()); load(fn, envir=e); as.list(e); }`. If you can guarantee that there will always be exactly one object in the `.rda` file, you can end it with `as.list(e)[[1]]` instead.

Comment: I'm struggling to work with this (readRDS doesn't load my plot), could you give me an example please?

Comment: @DavidJorquera it's a bit cheeky asking for an example, without having provided one yourself. I suggest you create your map, assign it to an object, save it using `saveRDS()`, then you can load it by going `mymap <- readRDS()`